# How to find where a positive word is in a set of documents after using Word2Vec?

Tags: python, machine-learning, word2vec

I am testing with Word2Vec to find words that have the same meaning, so far it is going great as the list of positive words is accurate. However, I would like to know where each positive word was found, as in which document.

I tried to iterate each document and compare each word with the list of positive words, something like this:

```
for i in documents: # iterating the documents
    for j in i: # iterating the words in the document
        for k in similar_words: # iterating the positive words
            if k[0] in j: # k[0] is the positive word, k[1] is the positive value
                print('found word')
```

This works fine. However, with this, the positive words are actually stemmed down, that is why I am using "in". So let's say the stemmed down positive word is 'ice', many words contain the phrase 'ice' in them, and maybe more than one are in the document and only one of them is the real positive word.

Is there a way to avoid stemming words when using Word2Vec? Or is there a way to find the document number of each positive word found?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code for training the model and using 'most_similar()'

```
def remove_stopwords(texts):
    # Removes stopwords in a text
    return [[word for word in simple_preprocess(str(doc)) if word not in stop_words] for doc in texts]


def sent_to_words(sentences):
    # Tokenize each sentence into a list of words and remove unwanted characters
    for sentence in sentences:
        yield(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentence), deacc=True))


df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx')
df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)

data = df['Comment Section'].values.tolist()

# Remove the new line character and single quotes
data = [re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', str(sent)) for sent in data]
data = [re.sub("\'", "", str(sent)) for sent in data]

# Convert our data to a list of words. Now, data_words is a 2D array,
# each index contains a list of words
data_words = list(sent_to_words(data))

# Remove the stop words
data_words_nostops = remove_stopwords(data_words)

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
            data_words_nostops,
            alpha=0.1,
            min_alpha=0.001,
            size=250,
            window=1,
            min_count=2,
            workers=10)

model.train(data_words_nostops, total_examples=len(data_words_nostops), epochs=10)

print(model.wv.vocab) # At this step, the words are not stemmed

positive = ['injuries', 'fail', 'dangerous', 'oil']

negative = ['train', 'westward', 'goods', 'calgary', 'car', 'automobile', 'appliance']

similar_words_size = array_length(model.wv.most_similar(positive=positive, negative=negative, topn=0))

for i in model.wv.most_similar(positive=positive, negative=negative, topn=similar_words_size):
    if len(i[0]) > 2:
        risks.append(i)
        print(risks) # At this step, the words are stemmed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of published `Word2Vec` work, including the original papers from Google, doesn't bother with word-stemming. If you have a large enough corpus, with many varied examples of each form of a word, then each form will get a pretty-good vector (& closely-positioned with other forms) even as the raw unstemmed words. (On the other hand, in smaller corpuses, stemming is more likely to help, by allowing all the different forms of a word to contribute their occurrences to a single good vector.)

During training, `Word2Vec` just watches the training texts go by for the nearby-words information it needs: it doesn't remember the contents of individual documents. If you need that info, you need to retain it outside `Word2Vec`, in your own code.

You could iterate over all documents to find occurrences individual words, as in your code. (And, as @alexey's answer notes, you should compare stemmed-words to stemmed-words, rather than just checking for substring-containment.)

The other option, used in full-text search, is to build a "reverse index" that remembers in which documents (and potentially where in each document) each word appears. Then, you essentially have a dictionary in which you look up "iced", and get back a list of documents like "doc1, doc17, doc42". (Or potentially, a list of docs-plus-positions, like "doc2:pos11,pos91; doc17:pos22, doc42:pos77".) That requires more work up-front, and storing the reverse-index (which depending on the level of detail retained, can be nearly as large as the original texts), but then finds docs-containing-words much faster than a full-iteration-search for each word.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Do you have any idea if I can use Word2Vec's stemming function to apply it and check whether the result stemmed word is equal to the stemmed word in the sentence?

Comment: Because I tried nltk's porterstemmer, but the stemmed word does not look the same as the stemmed words in Word2Vec

Comment: `Word2Vec` itself does not have a stemming function (and as noted above, much related work doesn't bother to stem). If you have a pretrained `Word2Vec` model (or simply set of final word-vectors) for which it appears stemming was used, you'll have to ask the creators of that data what stemming code they used.

Comment: When I train my model using Word2Vec, it automatically stems the words for me. I'm not sure if this is supposed to happen or what, but that's what I am going through, and what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: There's no such automatic stemming in the popular gensim `Word2Vec` implementation. (And it would be weird for any other implementation to do it automatically, too, as it's typically an optional preprocessing step.) So it's likely some other wrinkle of your code that's relevant, and you'd have to add to your question to show your training code to know why you're getting stemming if you didn't explicitly add that step yourself.

Comment: The words returned by `most_similar()` will be the words supplied when the model was trained. (If you're seeing stemmed-words in `most_similar()` results, then the data fed to the `Word2Vec` model had gone through a stemming step, before it was passed into `Word2Vec`.)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, its not actually after the model is trained, but after applying the 'most_similar' function, as it outputs stemmed down words

Comment: I tried printing the words before and after most_similar(), before it they were normal, after it they are stemmed down. Ill post my code in the question

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. I don't see any steps in that code which apply stemming, either before training, or after training, or upon the results of `most_similar()`. Are you sure you're not misinterpreting raw words that actually appeared in your `my_file.xlsx` text? (Perhaps, they were typos or stemmed before appearing in that file?) Any word that appears in `most_similar()` results will also have appeared inside `model.wv.vocab`. There will be no additional transformations to the words by `Word2Vec`/`most_similar()`. It will only return what words you fed it.

Comment: (If you think this is not the case, verify – and perhaps show in your question – some of the texts in your corpus, for example `data_words_nostops[0:2]`. Only request a smaller number of `topn` most-similars – say 10 – and show the actual results. Verify that each word in the `most_similar()` results was also in `model.wv.vocab` and also inside `data_words_nostops`.)

Comment: I actually think you are right, what has confused me is seeing this:
`'injuries'
'injuri'
'inju'
'inj'`
as an example of why I thought the model is stemmed down, but I am not sure why it is doing this, I dont see the other forms of 'injuries' anywhere in the data

Comment: While those are definitely prefix-substrings of `'injuries'`, they don't look like the results of either (1) stemming; or (2) taking *all* prefix-substrings. If you're seeing all those tokens in a `most_similar()` result, then they're also going to be in `model.wv.vocab` and were likely hidden somewhere in the input-corpus, as well – maybe a bunch of ad-hoc abbreviations? (That they might all be closely clustered in the same results could be a good sign: that each variant appears in enough similar training contexts for the model to learn they're essentially synonyms for each other.)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use the unstemmed word during word2vec model training. But in practice, doing this usually significantly reduces quality of resulting vectors.

In case you are using pre-trained vectors you have to use the same stemmer function that was used during training.

When you got one you can make a dictionary out of `similar_words` and then match words using `stem(word) in similar_words`

Comment: Is there any way to find where the positive word is in the documents?

Comment: your approach of iterating over document terms and checking every term is quite fine. or do you have problems with that?

Comment: the problem as I mentioned is that some words get different stemmed words, for example, if a positive word was "ice", then if a document has "ice", "police", "magnificent"; it will tag them all, while really only "ice" is needed

Comment: that why you should use `stem(word) == positive_word` instead of `positive_word in word`.